# xml group elements by nodename which changes by suffix

Tags: xml, transform, nodes

I am trying to transform an XML to specific output XML. But I could not group by  where N changes for a group of fields.

```
    <Balances>
        <Balances_Line_Item0>
          <Page>
            <Field>EmpID</Field>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
          </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item0>
        <Balances_Line_Item0>
          <Page>
            <Field>Name</Field>
            <Letter>53</Letter>
            <Letter>56</Letter>
            <Letter>76</Letter>
             <Letter>53</Letter>
            <Letter>56</Letter>
            <Letter>76</Letter>
         </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item0>
        <Balances_Line_Item0>
          <Page>
            <Field>Department</Field>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
          </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item0>
        <Balances_Line_Item1>
          <Page>
            <Field>EmpID</Field>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
          </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item1>
        <Balances_Line_Item1>
          <Page>
            <Field>Name</Field>
            <Letter>53</Letter>
            <Letter>56</Letter>
            <Letter>76</Letter>
             <Letter>53</Letter>
            <Letter>56</Letter>
            <Letter>76</Letter>
         </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item1>
        <Balances_Line_Item1>
          <Page>
            <Field>Department</Field>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
          </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item1>
        <Balances_Line_Item2>
          <Page>
            <Field>EmpID</Field>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
          </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item2>
        <Balances_Line_Item2>
          <Page>
            <Field>Name</Field>
            <Letter>53</Letter>
            <Letter>56</Letter>
            <Letter>76</Letter>
             <Letter>53</Letter>
            <Letter>56</Letter>
            <Letter>76</Letter>
         </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item2>
        <Balances_Line_Item2>
          <Page>
            <Field>Department</Field>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
            <Letter>45</Letter>
          </Page>
        </Balances_Line_Item2>
    </Balances>
```

My transformed XML should be:

```
<Balances>
<Balances_Line_Item0>
<EmpID>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
</EmpID>
<Name>
        <Letter>53</Letter>
        <Letter>56</Letter>
        <Letter>76</Letter>
         <Letter>53</Letter>
        <Letter>56</Letter>
        <Letter>76</Letter>
</Name>
<Dept>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
</Dept>
</Balances_Line_Item0>
<Balances_Line_Item1>
<EmpID>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
</EmpID>
<Name>
        <Letter>53</Letter>
        <Letter>56</Letter>
        <Letter>76</Letter>
         <Letter>53</Letter>
        <Letter>56</Letter>
        <Letter>76</Letter>
</Name>
<Dept>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
</Dept>
</Balances_Line_Item1>
<Balances_Line_Item2>
<EmpID>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
</EmpID>
<Name>
        <Letter>53</Letter>
        <Letter>56</Letter>
        <Letter>76</Letter>
         <Letter>53</Letter>
        <Letter>56</Letter>
        <Letter>76</Letter>
</Name>
<Dept>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
        <Letter>45</Letter>
</Dept>
</Balances_Line_Item2>
</Balances>
```

How can the input xml be transformed to above XML? Please suggest.

---

I applied one more transformation on the resulting xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="Balances">
        <xsl:for-each select="Balances/node()[position() mod 5 = 1]">
          <xsl:element name="LineItem">
            <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::node()[not(position() > 4)]">
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
          </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But my xslt is very basic and I cannot continue to use such XSL for still more complex transformations. Can some one suggest tweaked and much better xslt, probably one XSLT, rather than 2.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Balances">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Page">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Field"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Field">
    <xsl:element name="{.}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank You for the XSL. I tried using it with my Visual Studio 2010 solution using XslCompiledTransform. It failed loading the XSL mentioning that the for-each-group is not yet implemented.Tried google, but could not find an answer to fix that issue.

Comment: I did point out it was an XSLT 2.0 solution. XSLT 2.0 processors for .NET are available from Saxonica and XmlPrime. Microsoft's XML technologies are way out of date, and it's time you weaned yourself off them.

Comment: I dont have option. So, is it possible to replace for-each-group with any 1.0 version code snippet? I tried to write some xslt googling and understanding bits and pieces. Following the xslt:

Comment: Yes, it can be done with XSLT 1.0 but it's much more difficult and I don't have any motivation to help you with it.